# RSS 2.0 - How to verify it's working without uploading to website

Tags: rss

This will be a very basic question!

I'm wondering a bit about how RSS 2.0 works. I've made a quick document (with help from Wc3 of course), given it the .xml extension - but when I try to open it with Firefox it only gives me the document tree, because it apparently lacks style information. All I want to do is to learn about RSS 2.0 through trial and error, but I can't do that if I can't see the results of what I've written.

The document is copy-pasted from Wc3's tutorial; so the code shouldn't be significant.
Any ideas how I could go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try deploying it on local server. Setting up apache on windows/linux or wamp on windows should suffice. If you are using win, you can install iis express to try it.

Comment: Wow, really? There isn't an easier way to try this without setting up a local web-server? :P

Comment: Not that I know of. It needs to be served using http protocol by the browser to check if it's valid. Otherwise, you can try uploading it to http://www.validome.org/rss-atom/ to check if your xml is valid.